# Typescript-Button Event doesn't get triggered

Tags: html, typescript

Hey guys I just started learning typescript and I tried to code a javascript example in typescript but if I run the code and press the button nothing happens.

And I am also looking for me examples or resources to learn to integrate typescript in HTML as I am new to web programming but have many years of experience in java/python

typescript.ts

```
class Example{

    constructor(){
        let button=document.getElementById("b");
        button.addEventListener("click", (e:Event)=>this.feedTheButton)
    }

    greatestOfTwo=(first:number,second:number):number=>{
        if (first>second){
            return first
        }else{
            return second
        }
    }

    feedTheButton(){
       let first:number = parseInt((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("f")).value);
       let second:number=parseInt((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("d")).value);
       let result:number=this.greatestOfTwo(first,second)
       let place=document.getElementById("write")
       place.innerHTML=result.toString()

    }
}
new Example();
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="typescript.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            Type a number
            <input type="text" id="f" size="4"> 
            </p>
            <p> Type another number 
                <input type="text" id="s" size="4">
            </p>
        <button id="b" class="myButton" value="click">Get The Larger Number</button>
        <P>The Larger number of the two is: <span id="wrote"></span></P>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you compile your typescript? Typescript isn't ran directly by the browser, it needs to be compiled into Javascript.

Comment: Have you read the [typescript docs?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html)

Comment: @Liam yeah iam using vsCode and i compile my typescript

Comment: Have you [debugged the resulting js](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/)?

Comment: @Liam yeah i did i get reference error at -> var button = document.getElementById("b");
                     ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: Move the script tag to the end of the body section. In the head the body is not loaded yet. (or execute new Example() on load event)

Comment: @lujcon i did but i get the error reference error in the compiled js, see above u

Comment: @nastan, I've done this for you, please edit the question to add details and try and avoid adding details just in comments

Comment: @nastan are you getting the error in the browser ( browser's console)? It looks like you are executing the script somewhere else (node ?). You have to open the html file in the browser.

Comment: @lujcon i get the error in vscode when i compile my ts file to js but the code works on browser now. any idea why i get the error in vsCode?

Comment: @nastan in tsconfig.json you have to add 'dom' to lib section.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: @ thanks a lot for ur effort !

Answer (score -1):

Directly pass the **this.feedTheButton** function as a parameter.

```
class Example{

    constructor(){
        let button=document.getElementById("b");
        button.addEventListener("click", this.feedTheButton.bind(this)) // Directly pass the function as parameter
    }

    greatestOfTwo=(first:number,second:number):number=>{
        if (first>second){
            return first
        }else{
            return second
        }
    }

    feedTheButton(e){
       let first:number = parseInt((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("f")).value);
       let second:number=parseInt((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("s")).value); // Changed this value to 's' because your input id is 's'
       let result:number=this.greatestOfTwo(first,second)
      let place=document.getElementById("wrote")
       place.innerHTML=result.toString()

    }
}
new Example();
```

Your html should be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            Type a number
            <input type="text" id="f" size="4"> 
            </p>
            <p> Type another number 
                <input type="text" id="s" size="4">
            </p>
        <button id="b" class="myButton" value="click">Get The Larger Number</button>
        <P>The Larger number of the two is: <span id="wrote"></span></P>

<script src="typescript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i get reference error when i try to compile the code into javascript-> var button = document.getElementById("b");
                     ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: by passing method directly you don't have correct reference to `this`. Instead you should pass this.feedTheButton.bind(this)

Comment: @nastan i have updated the answer with correct id values in both html as well as typescript. you have mismatched some of the ids. pls try this code

Comment: Thanks guys is does work on browser atleast. What was wrong in my first code if i may ask? running the script tag in the head or the button.addEventlistener part?

Comment: @nastan Yes, you should run the script at the bottom, before closing the body tag. You also misspelled some of the HTML  id's in your typescript